# UIPageViewController/TextKit count number of pages

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, textkit

How can I count the number of pages of text if I have a very long NSTextStorage and I know CGSize of NSTextContainer?
Is there a standard procedure for this thing or some way to count it dynamically?
I can't find a good tutorial to make an iBooks like book from raw text with custom fonts (I need to draw texts of 20-50 pages).

Answer (score 1):

I found a good way to count a number of pages using TextKit's NSLayoutManager. Just count pages when I create NSTextContainers

```
    var range = NSMakeRange(0, 0)
    var containerIndex : UInt = 0
    var pageIndex : UInt = 1
    while(NSMaxRange(range) < layoutManager.numberOfGlyphs) {
        let textViewRect = self.frameForViewAtIndex(containerIndex)
        let containerSize = CGSizeMake(textViewRect.size.width, textViewRect.size.height - 16)
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: containerSize)
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)

        let textView = UITextView(frame: textViewRect, textContainer: textContainer)
        self.addSubview(textView)
        range = (layoutManager.glyphRangeForTextContainer(textContainer))

        containerIndex++;
        if containerIndex%columnCount == 0 { pageIndex++ }
    }
```

columnCount is the number of columns if you'll use multicolumn layout

frameForViewAtIndex returns CGRect for current textView inside scrollView